# SQL Query - All leisures of a person

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new here. I thought I could ask for some help here on my php-sql homework.
I've been trying to extract all the sports associated to a registered person using SQL.

There are three tables in my mySql.

**personnes** which stores the individuals

```
[id]  [sexe]  [etat_civil]  [nom]    [prenom]
1     Homme    M.           Smith    Alex
2     Femme    Mme          Alisha   Elektra
3     Femme    Mll          Lord     Yves
```

**loisirs** which stores the types of sports or leisures

```
id  nom
1   Sport
2   Concert
3   Jeux vidéo
4   Jeux société
5   Voyage
6   Cinéma
7   Lecture
8   Théâtre
9   Danse
10  Animaux
11  Randonnée
12  Shopping
```

**personnes_loisirs** which stores the foreign key of the individuals which associated foreign keys id.

```
[id]   [fk_personnes]  [fk_loisirs]
1      1                1
2      1                2 
3      1                3
4      2                1
5      2                3
6      2                4
7      2                5
8      3                7
9      3                8
10     3                9
```

Basically, I've been successful to extract the sport of a user but only if there's only 1 sport associated to him. Where there are more than 1, I fail to get the rest of it.

Here's the SQL

```
select nom 
from `loisirs` 
where id in 
  (select fk_loisirs 
   from `personnes_loisirs`    
   where id in 
     (select id 
      from `personnes` 
      where sexe='Homme' AND nom='Smith' AND prenom='Alex'))
```

This returns me 'Sport' but not 'Sport, Concert and Jeux Vidéo';

I think I must use JOIN to be able to retrieve all the 'loisirs' associated to SmithAlex
But I'm not sure how.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select l.nom
from personnes p
join personner_loisirs pl on p.id = pl.fk_personnes
join loisirs l on l.id = pl.fk_loisirs
where p.nom = 'Smith' and p.prenom='Alex'
```

Comment: MERCI beaucoup! It's working so far, now I just need to deal with my php code. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 2):

Your subquery is not correct.  You shouldn't say `where id in...` you should say `where fk_personnes in...`

Answer (score 2):

In your original query you made an error when checking for the link between `personnes_loisirs` and `personnes` - you're returning the `id` from `personnes` in the final query but you should be using `fk_personnes`.  Basically this is a very good demonstration of why fields just named `id` can be confusing...

In addition you should then measure that against another way of constructing the query e.g.

```
select l.nom
from personnes p
  inner join personnes_loisirs pl on pl.[fk_personnes] = p.[id]
  inner join loisirs l on l.[id] = pl.fk_loisirs
where p.sexe='Homme' 
  and p.nom='Smith'
  and p.prenom='Alex'
```

Comment: You're right. I just figured that out too.
By the way, I'm still not used to 'join'. I think the 'l' and 'p' is the way to code for the joining stuff able to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query : (not tested)

```
SELECT loisirs.* 
FROM loisirs 
   INNER JOIN personnes_loisirs ON personnes_loisirs.fk_loisirs = loisirs.id 
   INNER JOIN personnes ON personnes_loisirs.fk_personnes = personnes.id 
WHERE personnes.sexe='Homme' 
   AND personnes.nom='Smith' 
   AND personnes.prenom='Alex'
;
```

Comment: Bear in mind, that this is a homework and you should rather help and not present a solution.

Comment: #1052 - Column 'nom' in where clause is ambiguous
I got this error, unfortunately I'm not sure what it means :(

Comment: It's ok. This site makes programming more social so to speak. Thanks ;)